# Work in exchange for food and dorming at a Buddhist temple

Tags: europe, work, sleeping, north-africa

For a while, I've been fantasizing about running away to a Buddhist temple for a month or so to work in exchange for hours of group meditation time, dorming, and food. I'm going to be spending the next 7 months abroad (starting in Spain) traveling with no specific plan in mind.

Any ideas on where/how to find a Buddhist Temple w/ this description.

I'm familiar w/ wwoof, but no luck thus far. Any other resources if you don't have specifics in mind?

---

*Edit not from OP to incorporate part of Comment from OP*:

> anywhere "within reach" of Spain, so Europe or Northern Africa

Comment: What does abroad mean when you start in spain? The whole world, europe, also SE Asia?

Comment: Preferably anywhere "within reach" of Spain, so Europe or Northern Africa.

Answer (score 6):

[Cittaviveka](http://cittaviveka.org/index.php/support/helping-out) might suit:

> Cittaviveka does not receive support from any powerful backers or
>   institutions; it sells nothing and all teachings as well as books are
>   given freely. No charge is made for people to stay here; the resident
>   Sangha is prohibited from possessing or dealing in money. The
>   community draws from its own skills to keep the monastery going, and
>   in this is aided by various lay advisory committees. The Cittaviveka
>   Advisory Group and the English Sangha Trust supervise these.
>
> Cittaviveka is completely dependent on donations. It is financially
>   managed by the English Sangha Trust, a registered charity which can
>   receive and administer any such donations. The Trust Secretary will be
>   happy to answer any queries concerning the nature of the Trust. Also,
>   please see the 'By offering money' link below.
>
> There are several ways to support Cittaviveka;
>
> By offering money – to the monastery steward or lay Treasurer.
>
> By offering requisites – such as food, furnishings, equipment.
>
> By offering service – in terms of skills or advice.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chithurst_Buddhist_Monastery):

[image: Cittaviveka]

> It is situated in West Sussex, England in the hamlet of Chithurst between Midhurst and Petersfield.

Answer (score 4):

There are temples in Thailand and other SE Asian destinations who would accept a foreigner who wanted to learn and meditate.  You wouldn't "work for food" but rather you will share the temple chores with the rest of the monks, help with alms rounds and eat from the offerings, meditate, basically follow the route of a novice monk.

I don't know of any apps or organization that will point you to a temple, you simply have to ask around.  Accepting foreigners / non-believers is up to the temple's abbot and you would likely be the only foreigner in residence.

Comment: @pnuts - the question was edited after I posted my answer.

Comment: @pnuts - in my view tags are keywords for searching and sorting, not a part of the question, and a large percentage of posters don't know how to select appropriate ones.  The OPs use of Europe could for where he is or where he is going. And with 7 months traveling could range far beyond Europe.